# SubView transition resizing after transition

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, uicontainerview

I have a container view controller and child view controllers (Similar to UITabViewController). When transitioning between the view of one child view controller and another child view controller's view, I am using:

```
let oldView = // get reference to old view
let newView = // get reference to new view
UIView.transition(from: oldView!, to: newView!, duration: 0.3,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)
```

The issue here, is that the resizing of the newView happens after the transition animation completes, which looks unsightly.

This bad behavior is only happening when the new child view controller is loaded **for the very first time**. It seems that the viewDidLayoutSubviews method is only called after the transition.

How do I get the newView to be resized BEFORE the transition and not after.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The transition itself works fine with Auto Layout. I just tested that. You need to show more of your code – especially the code where you add and setup the child view controller(s).

Comment: How do you resize the (new) child view controller's view to match the size of the container?

Comment: have you tried overriding `func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`
and add your transition inside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `ViewController` override `func viewWillTransition` 
so it will be something like this

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let oldView = // get reference to old view
let newView = // get reference to new view
UIView.transition(from: oldView!, to: newView!, duration: 0.3,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: do not forget, that this method will also be called if the Screen rotates into landscape or portrait mode.

Comment: thanks for the warning, I should have mentioned that.